Time complexity for evaluating prime factors using trial division
I am trying to find the prime factors and I am doing so by going through each number from $d=2$ upto $d=\lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor}$, and dividing the remaining number by $d$ until it cannot be divided completely anymore.
vector<int> primeFactors(int n) {
    vector<int> pf;           // stores the prime factors
    for (d=2 to d*d<=n) {
        if (n != 1) {
            break;
        }
        if (n%d == 0) {       // d occurs at least once in the prime factorisation of n
            pf.push_back(d);
        }
        while (n%d == 0) {    // reduce the power of d in n to 0
            n = n/d;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {              // if after traversing all numbers in range 2 to sqrt(n), n>1, n is prime
        pf.push_back(n);
    }
    return pf;
}

I am unable to understand how the time complexity of the algorithm comes out to be $O(\sqrt{n})$. If we represent the number $n=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}p_{i}^{a_{i}}$, where $p_{i}\in P, a_{i}\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$. Then the complexity should be $O(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i})$. But how does that come out to be $O(\sqrt{n})$. Any hints or thoughts are appreciated. Thanks.

If we try all numbers (not just the primes) , we need in the worst case $\sqrt{n}$ trial divisions (the exact value is close enough to this , if $n$ is large to make no difference). Therefore the complexity is $O(\sqrt{n})$

@Peter Is there a way to get a tighter bound, like can we express $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}$ in terms of $n$ somehow?

As you pointed out you can stop at $\sqrt{n}$ since the remaining factors can easily be determined , this $\sqrt{n}$ is extremely tight (just about one off the actual value). What do you mean with a tighter bound ?

This method needs $O(\sqrt n)$ when $n$ is prime to certify that it's prime, therefore $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} T(n)/\sqrt{n}>0$ by all means.

It is $O(\sqrt{n})$. As you pointed out, we should also take into account the steps of the loop taking out all factors. This is $O(\sum_i a_i)$ where $n = \prod_i p_i^{a_i}$, but noticing that $p_i \ge 2 \implies n \ge 2^{(\sum_i a_i)}$ tells us that $\sum_i a_i \le \log_2 n$, so the algorithm has complexity $O(\sqrt{n} + \log n) = O(\sqrt{n})$.
